# Prevent Ubuntu 10.04 from locking display after few minutes of inactivity

Tags: power-management, gnome-screensaver

My system is Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx. I looked under System/Preferences/Power Management and everything is set to Never. How do I change settings so I can let the screen stay on at least for 30 minutes or whatever I need?

Answer (score 1):

You are not being logged out, it is locking the screen.  Disable the lock screen by going

```
System -> preferences -> screensaver
```

You might also want to also change the screensaver value to a more reasonable time, or disable it.

Please be aware that support for 10.04 LTS runs out in April.  You might want to look at upgrading to 12.04 LTS which is supported until 2017

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Also appreciate the heads-up on the upgrade/support.